# Pandas merge returning an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I believe there is an issue with my merge function because when I try to add the three datasets together, I return an empty dataframe with the variables 2016_visitation 2017_visitation 2018_visitation 2019_visitation at the top of the header. I had an assertion error tell me it couldn't find the column 'state' so I'm wondering if it's pulling information from the original unedited data or if I need to include another import function? Maybe another column rename? My merge function could use some tweaking overall but I'm not sure what would work best.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def load_data():

    # importing datasets
    df_2017=pd.read_excel('assets/US_States_Visited_2017.xlsx', skiprows=6,skipfooter=13)
    df_2018=pd.read_excel('assets/US_States_Visited_2018.xlsx', skiprows=7,skipfooter=7)
    df_2019=pd.read_excel('assets/US_States_Visited_2019.xlsx', skiprows=6,skipfooter=8)
    
    # renaming columns
    df_2017.columns = ['2017_rank','state','2016_market_share','2016_visitation','2017_market_share','2017_visitation','volume_change']
    df_2018.columns = ['2018_rank','state','2018_market_share','2018_visitation','volume_change','2017_market_share','2017_visitation']
    df_2019.columns = ['2019_rank','state','2019_market_share','2019_visitation','volume_change','2018_market_share','2018_visitation']
    
    # dropping all columns except for relevent state and visitation columns
    df_2017.drop(df_2017.columns[[0,2,4,6]], axis=1,inplace=True)
    df_2018.drop(df_2018.columns[[0,2,4,5,6]], axis=1,inplace=True)
    df_2019.drop(df_2019.columns[[0,2,4,5,6]], axis=1,inplace=True) 
    
    # multiplying visitation by 1000 to get accurate value
    df_2017['2016_visitation'] = df_2017['2016_visitation']*1000
    df_2017['2017_visitation'] = df_2017['2017_visitation']*1000
    df_2018['2018_visitation'] = df_2018['2018_visitation']*1000
    df_2019['2019_visitation'] = df_2019['2019_visitation']*1000
    
    # starting output at state column
    df_2017=df_2017.set_index('state')
    df_2018=df_2018.set_index('state')
    df_2019=df_2019.set_index('state')
    
    # merging all datasets by state variable
    merge = pd.merge(df_2017,df_2018,on="state")
    merged_US_states_visitation = pd.merge(merge,df_2019,on='state')
    
    # sorting alphabetically
    merged_US_states_visitation.sort_values(by=['state'])
    
    return merged_US_states_visitation

load_data().head(25)
```

Comment: `merged_US_states_visitation = df_2017.merge(df_2018, on='state').merge(df_2019, on='state')` ?

Comment: Still outputting an empty dataframe. When I incorporate a "how" statement, I am getting an output of the merger but some columns come up as NaN. This statement merged the data together but only data in the 2019_visitation comes through and the rest are NaN. Perhaps too many how statements? merge = df_2017.merge(df_2018,on="state",how= 'left').merge(df_2019,on='state',how='right')

Comment: If you can put some of data for all of those dataframes, we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: seems like a dtype issue. make sure both columns you are merging on has same dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the 'state' column didn't match the values in the variable so I included df_201x['state'] = df_201x['state'].str.strip() which solved the formatting issues and merged the data.